# Derived operator< receiving Base object as parameter

Tags: c++, inheritance

I know that a derived class "is a" base class, therefore you can always pass a derived object to a base member function. Now, I was wondering about the reverse situation specifically with comparing operators (base class is not abstract and has objects).

Lets say I have:

```
class Base:
{
    public:
        Base(int m1, string m2);
        virtual ~Base();
        int GetM1()const;
        string GetM2()const;

        virtual bool operator<(const Base& base)const;

    private:
        int m1;
        string m2;
};
```

And I want to do something like this:

```
class Derived: public Base
{
    public:
    Derived(string member);
    ~Derived();

    virtual bool operator<(const Base& base)const; // is this possible(without cast)???

};
```

Thanks

Comment: The Derived operator will be used when you do `someDerivedObject < someBaseObject`, where `someBaseObject` can be anything derived from `Base`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. The `Derived` opererator will be used in code like this:

```
Base b;
Derived d;
if (d < b) {
    ...
}
```

You could also have some other class derived from `Base`, such as `Derived1`, and it will be used:

```
Derived1 d1;
Derived d;
if (d < d1) {
    ...
}
```